# My transaction was reverted but my funds were never returned back to my wallet

Tags: tokens, revert

My transaction failed with error code displaying “REVERTED”. My funds were never sent back to my wallet. When I try to claim on Uniswap says not supported. I run updated version, I have tried everything. Here is the TX:

TX: 0x7f1211b1cfb2869e06c27850b0cf3ca043aa84d20be9031df2042078ea6c5d50

Uniswap: 0x8634E0538429c1f519d57c2b3dE4104d9bE8fff2

Answer (score 0):

The funds were never sent back because the funds never left the sender wallet.

You an look the the state changes caused by the reverted [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7f1211b1cfb2869e06c27850b0cf3ca043aa84d20be9031df2042078ea6c5d50#statechange).

- sender `0x8634E0...9bE8fff2` paid 0.00650424051270578
- block producer received 0.00650424051270578